# How do I know you have logged in a Sharepoint WebPage?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

We use Sharepoint as CMS for our webpages at work. I know how to create controls that can be only visible if you have logged in in SharePoint with:

<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl1" runat="server" PermissionsString="AddAndCustomizePages"><br />
<Sharepoint:CssLink  ID="CssLink1" runat="server"/><br />
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>

But I want to know how to make controls visible (or whatever) programmatically depending on permissions.

I cannot use the methods for .NET windows form authentication like:

```
        if (!(HttpContext.Current.User == null) && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){}
```

because we use this for anonymous users who has another type of log in.

Could you provide some code? I know that it must be something like verifying  the SPContext.Current.FormContext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are the users authenticated? With forms authentication or Windows/active directory?

If active directory, then I think in that case you might need to get a reference to the current SPWeb, and then do web.CurrentUser.ID. This might come out null when you are anonymous. If not, try web.SiteUsers.GetByID(web.CurrentUser.ID) and see what you get.

Comment: They are authenticated through Sharepoint administration who is linked to Active Directory. The thing is there is a Sharepoint API to do these things but I have not had the time to look at this part.

Comment: I think in that case you might need to get a reference to the current SPWeb, and then do web.CurrentUser.ID. This might come out null when you are anonymous. If not, try web.SiteUsers.GetByID(web.CurrentUser.ID) and see what you get.

Comment: Could you put your commentary in your answer so that i can vote it? I have finally verified SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser is not null

Answer (score 1):

[DoesUserHavePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms456041.aspx)

You can use this method on the current web to check if the current user has a specific permission.

I assume your authenticated users have some permission to check for that the anonymous crowd is denied.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tested it, I imagine the LoginName property of the SPUser object will be blank, or throw an exception.

... of course, its never safe to presume anything when dealing w/the SharePoint OM :(